# css liquid layout with div overflow inside

Tags: css, layout, html, overflow, liquid

I'm having trouble in design layout css with div element.

Basically my main page layout design is look like the following picture :

[image]

The red box is the browser screen area.
The black box is the content area where the data will included / or loaded via ajax.
The green box is the data list which is the response result and contain about hundred rows inside. The data list contain header div and rows divs.

What i intend to do is set the overflow on the blue area which is the data rows so the scrollbar will appear on the right side of the blue box not on the right side of the red or black box.
Then when the browser area (red) resized all the div inside will also resized to the best size.

I've managed to make the scroll bar appear on the blue box when the data inside is overflow by set css overflow : auto /scroll for blue box div. But the problem is the overflow : auto properties seems only work when i set a certain height for the blue box div let's say about 400px. When i resize the browser the blue box div keeps stay with 400px height.

How to make it auto resize? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried setting percentage based height?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't let the browser do the scrolling for you instead of using the DIVs scrollbar?

Comment: This would be easier to answer if there was some code to look at. Consider making a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) test case showing what you have so far.

Comment: @Robert, would you please help me to how to do it ?

Comment: @Dave, the reason is to avoid long scrolling down the browser and so i won't lost focus on the menus placed on the HEADER section and also several links placed on the FOOTER section.

Comment: @Donut, Thanks for edit my question and show the picture :)

Comment: Here is the link to jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pYYFD/ to show what i have so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix the heights of the HEADER, "Table Heading Row", FOOTER and the "subfooter" row

from there you can calculate the top and bottom position offsets for the middle box, which should be absolutely positioned, the becasue it's positioned you will also need to absolutely position the two bottom footers, in my example I have wrapped them two rows and positioned them as one, this may seem excess but there are in fact a lot of your containers which are no longer required (though I didn't weed them out)

also your float code is too excessive, you don't need to relatively position every float to left: 0.0% so I chopped all tham out, you only need top relatively position something if you want to do absolute positioning inside it.. except for the body element which is all we need to use for this style layout (note I did change the end of your HTML slightly)

#### refiddle: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/TR7ms/)

and btw, I think this one those internal rows would be better as an actual `<table>`, it seems like rows of Data to me ;) - and the whole thing would  likely mean a lot less code..

Comment: Thank you claire..., exactly what i want. Works perfectly & nicely on FF & Chrome. On IE the rows data wont showed up. I user IE 7. When i switch the rows data from div elements to table, it showed up. but the overflow scrollbar wasn't working. Is it problem with my IE version ? I'm downloading the version 8 right now and going to test it again. Anyway thank you so much for refiddle my code. :)

Comment: no problem.. it's working OK in my IE7 (I still use it for testing, if it works in that it usually just works ;)) - if you do decide  to switch to a table you will still need to wrap in a single div to take care of the scrolling - anyway if you're still having problems stick your code in a fiddle and I'll recheck..

Comment: I've upgraded to IE8, still not working... :( can't figure out where it goes wrong. I did'n change anything except for the table list header and rows. Used <div>... before now i switch to <table><tr>....

Comment: The similar case with this (desktop version application) is spread sheet application layout i.e ms.office excel. The scroll only affected the rows. The main menu (header), footer and the column header (A - Z) still remain while the rows scrolling up/down/left/right.

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is a positioned div for the blue box.

```
.blueboxdiv{
   position: relative;
   top     : 100px; // height of header - Top stays 100px away from header thus grows on resize!
   bottom  : 0px;   // Bottom sticks to bottom
   left    : 0px;   // Left sticks to left
   right   : 0px;   // Right sticks to right
}
```